# Image Load using two different type bitmap and picasso

Tags: android, listview

Wanted to load my camera intent images like this

`Bitmapbitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s.getImageUrl());
 vh.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

And my gallery intent images like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
```

How to put this condition in my adapter class.

**My Activity**

```
 public class CommonChattingAttachmentActivity extends BaseActivity {

    Realm realm;
    RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener;
    CCAA adapter;
    ListView lv;
    EditText descEditTxt;
    boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
    String userChoosenTask;
    TextView descTxt;
    ImageView imgallery,imgcam,img;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1888;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 1889;
   // private static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101;
    ImageView imgattach;
    View commonchat,functions,vi;
    TextView name;
    String h;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView imgcopy;
    private Intent[] intentArray;
    ImageView imgdelete;
    private String stringPathType;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_chatting_attachment);

        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        commonchat = findViewById(R.id.commonchat);
        functions = findViewById(R.id.functions);
        LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llcc);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_commonchat, null); //log.xml is your file.

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                CommonChat items = (CommonChat) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5e5e5"));
                change2();

            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                CommonChat item = (CommonChat) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a9a9a9"));
                change1();
                h=item.getDescription();
                onclick();
               // onitemclick();
                return true;

            }
        });


        //ll.addView(name);

         imgcopy = (ImageView) functions.findViewById(R.id.imagecopy);
         imgdelete=(ImageView) functions.findViewById(R.id.imgdelete);


        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
       // addImages();
        setAdapter();
        displayInputDialog();
        imgcam=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgcam);
        imgallery=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imggallery);
        imgattach=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgattach);
        imgallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                galleryIntent();
            }
        });
        imgcam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraIntent();
                //setAdapters();
                //Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"its done again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        imgattach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

    }
public void onclick()
{
    imgcopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(h);
        }
    });
    imgdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String type = h;
            final RealmResults<CommonChat> students = realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll();

            CommonChat CommonChat = students.where().equalTo("description", type).findFirst();

            if (CommonChat != null) {

                if (!realm.isInTransaction()) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                }

                CommonChat.removeFromRealm();

                realm.commitTransaction();
              //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
            //final int position2 = holder.getAdapterPosition();



    });

}

    public void setAdapter()
    {
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper=new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        helper.retrieveFromDB();
        CCAA adapter=new CCAA(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        realmChangeListener=new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                CCAA adapter=new CCAA(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }
    public void setAdapters()
    {
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper=new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        //helper.retrieveFromDB();
//        adapter=new CCAA(this,helper.justRefresh());
//        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
//        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       realmChangeListener=new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                //adapter=new CCAA(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    //DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
    public void displayInputDialog()
    {

        //EDITTEXTS
        descEditTxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editwrite);
        ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);

        //SAVE
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // descTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String desc = descEditTxt.getText().toString();
                CommonChat s = new CommonChat();
                s.setDescription(desc);
                CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
                if (helper.save(s)) {
                    descEditTxt.setText("");
                    setAdapter();
                   // addImages();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }




        });
    }
    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
//        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
//        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
//        intentArray = new Intent[]{intent2,intent1};
//        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        intent.putExtra("camera",REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }
    public void galleryIntent() {
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECT_FILE);
//        Intent intent = new Intent();
//        intent.setType("image/*");
//        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
//        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
    }
    public void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();
                }

                    else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
//                Picasso.with(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this).load(data.getData()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img));
               // getIntent().putExtra("gallery",SELECT_FILE);
            }
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
                //getIntent().putExtra("gallery",REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
//        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
//        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
//        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
//                null);
//        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
//        cursor.moveToFirst();
//
//        String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
//
//        Bitmap bm;
//        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
//        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
//        int scale = 1;
//        while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
//                && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
//            scale *= 2;
//        options.inSampleSize = scale;
//        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
//        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

        //ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(bm));
        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"My bm"+bm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // setAdapter();
       // addImages();
    }
    public void  onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"No Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"Error Arrived",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"Error Arrived again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(destination));
        //setAdapter();
       // addImages();
        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"its done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
    public void SaveImageVideoData(String data) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            //CommonChat s = new CommonChat();
            s.setImageUrl(data);
            s.setVideoUrl(data);

            s.setMediaPathType(stringPathType);
            // obj.setExtensionTypeValue(stringMediaExtType);

            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
            if (helper.save(s)) {
                setAdapter();
                // addImages();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //setAdapter();
            //setAdapters();
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Set Image URL"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope its not done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public void addImages() {

        CommonChatRealmHelper helper=new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        RealmResults<CommonChat> CommonChats=realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll();
        final ArrayList<CommonChat> latest=new ArrayList<>();
        for (CommonChat s : CommonChats)
        {
           latest.add(s);
           Log.d("Testing",String.valueOf(s));
        }

        CCAA adapter = new CCAA(this, latest);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        //showMediaCount();
        //lv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
//        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
//        //RETRIEVE
//        CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
//
//        ArrayList<CommonChat> surveyList = new ArrayList<>();
//        //Mohit Code
//        //RealmResults<UserSurveyMedia> spacecrafts=realm.where(UserSurveyMedia.class).equalTo("user_survey_id",userSurveyId).equalTo("question_id",getQuestionId()).equalTo("mediatype",stringMediaType).findAll();
//        RealmResults<CommonChat> spacecrafts = realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll();
//
//        for (CommonChat s : spacecrafts) {
//            surveyList.add(s);
//        }
//
//        //BIND
//        CCAA adapter = new CCAA(this, surveyList);
//        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void change1()
    {
        commonchat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        functions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public void change2()
    {
        commonchat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        functions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();}
}
```

**My Adapter Class**

```
public class CCAA extends ArrayAdapter<CommonChat> {
    List<CommonChat> contactList;
    String camera;
//Intent intent;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CCAA(Context context, List<CommonChat> objects){
        super(context,0,objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        contactList = objects;


    }



    @Override
    public CommonChat getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final CCAA.ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_commonchat, parent, false);
            vh = CCAA.ViewHolder.create((LinearLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (CCAA.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        CommonChat s = getItem(position);






        //final CommonChat s= (CommonChat) this.getItem(position);

        if(vh.txtbeencnt!=null) {
            vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vh.txtbeencnt.setText(s.getDescription());
        }




        //final int position2 = vh.getAdapterPosition();

        if(s.getImageUrl() != null && s.getImageUrl().length()>0)
        {
//            if(imageUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("camera"))
//            {
                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s.getImageUrl());
                vh.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
                Toast.makeText(context,"Got Image URL"+s.getImageUrl(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(s.getImageUrl() != null && s.getImageUrl().length()>0)
            {
                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
                Toast.makeText(context,"Got Image URL"+s.getImageUrl(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


//        else
//        {
//            vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
//            Toast.makeText(context,"Got Image URL"+s.getImageUrl(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        }

        //downloadImage(c,imageUrl,img);

        //Utility.downloadImage(c,imageUrl,img);





        //vh.txtbeencnt.setText(String.valueOf(s.getDescription()));


       // Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);

        return vh.rootView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final LinearLayout rootView;
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView txtbeencnt;
        public final VideoView videoView;


        private ViewHolder(LinearLayout rootView, ImageView imageView,TextView txtbeencnt,VideoView videoView) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.txtbeencnt = txtbeencnt;
            this.videoView=videoView;

        }

        public static CCAA.ViewHolder create(LinearLayout rootView) {
           ImageView  imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            VideoView  videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            TextView txtbeencnt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
            return new CCAA.ViewHolder(rootView,imageView,txtbeencnt,videoView);
        }


    }
}
```

**My Edited Activity Using Flag**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(bm),true);
        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"My bm"+bm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void  onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"No Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"Error Arrived",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"Error Arrived again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(destination),false);
        Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this,"its done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
    public void SaveImageVideoData(String data,boolean flag) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            s.setImageUrl(data);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
            if (helper.save(s)) {
                setAdapter();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Set Image URL"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope its not done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**My Edited Adapter Using Flag**

```
 if(s.getImageUrl() != null && s.getImageUrl().length()>0) {
            if (flag == true) {
                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Image URL" + s.getImageUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (flag == false) {

                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s.getImageUrl());
                vh.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Image URL" + s.getImageUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: where have you set the flag value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialise the image to image view with respective procedure before calling the saveimagevideoData function in `"onSelectFromGalleryResult"` and `"onCaptureImageResult"`

If in adapter:
Add a flag along with data String in `saveimagevideoData` function. Detect the flag and assign the image respectively to imageView

```
public void SaveImageVideoData(String data,boolean flag) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            s.setImageUrl(data);
            //Create a variable for flag in CommonChat and set the flag like url(s.setImageUrl(data))
            s.setFlag(flag);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
            if (helper.save(s)) {
                setAdapter();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Set Image URL"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope its not done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Then in the adapter

```
if(s.getImageUrl() != null && s.getImageUrl().length()>0) {
            boolean flag= s.getFlag();
            if (flag == true) {
                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Picasso.with(context).load(s.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Image URL" + s.getImageUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (flag == false) {

                vh.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vh.txtbeencnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                vh.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s.getImageUrl());
                vh.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Image URL" + s.getImageUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Passing flag along with images is the best way to distinguish, as i believe.

Comment: can u plz clarify your suggestion sir!! I didn't get what you said because my imageview is in adapter class where i wanted to load my image.

Comment: pass the flag to common chat class as well along with getImageUrl

Comment: I tried to distinguish between both the method using flag but only camera images are loaded not the gallery images. Please look at my edited code and tell me where i am wrong

Comment: I dint not find any code which send decides true or false for camera and gallery

Comment: Sir I set the third parameter in saveimagevideodata method called boolean flag. And for making difference i called one method with true parameter and other with false parameter.

Comment: Set the flag along like the way you are setting url, i will post an example

Comment: Thank you Sir! This code helps in making difference between loading image of camera and gallery but when i load my gallery image the picasso placeholder image arrives. is there any error in my gallery intent or onselectfromgalleryresult() method?

Comment: @AasthaDoshi Check if you have placed a placeholder/src in the xml file of imageview